# Enabling the PHP Mail() Function in Parallels Plesk

Tags: php, email, plesk

I am trying to get some PHP scripts to use the PHP Mail function on my site using our 1and1 mail server credentials.

I am running Parallel Plesk on a Windows Server.

From logging into plesk and checking the specific site I can see I am running PHP 5.4

After following this link

[Setup PHP.ini with Plesk](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213411789-PHP-mail-function-does-not-work)

I have gone to;

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Paralells\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP54\php.ini

and ammended to the following;

```
SMTP = auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk
smtp_port = 587
auth_username = username
auth_password = password
sendmail_from = myemail
```

The PHP Script being used is as follows;

```
<?php
    $method =  $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
    if ($method == "POST") {
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $recipient = "test@myemail.com";
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";
        $email_content = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $email_content);
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";
        //mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content);
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }
    } else {
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }
?>
```

a 500 Error is always returned at this point. can anyone direct me as to what I am doing wrong here?

As an update if I go to

Tools & Settings -> Mail Server Settings

I can see Mail Enable is installed and running (if I go to Webmail i can see this is version 9).

I have also then tried going to the following

Tools & Settings -> External SMTP Server Settings

and unchecking the Use the mail server installed with Plesk and the default mail account created by Plesk option and completing this.

However, its still not working?

Comment: Check PHP error log. Since Plesk 12.5 you can see php error log in Plesk UI on domain or in `C:\inetpub\vhosts\domain.tld\logs\php_errors\domain.tld`. In older Plesk version error log can be set manually via php.ini